# how to configure CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) in systemD service?

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, node.js

setting CORS  (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) in systemD service doesn't work.

I have a node module with CORS  (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) enabled, now my question is how can I move the CORS configuration from the code to systemd service?

current setup in the code:

```
private allowCrossDomain(req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: () => void) {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization, Content-Type');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
        next();
    }
```

instead I'd like to add CORS in myService.service, the but below setup doesn't work:

```
[unit]
Description=Tool operation BE
After=network.target
[Service]
User=ubuntu
Environment=BACKEND_HOST=backend-ops-model.com
Environment=BACKEN_MODEL_PORT=80
Environment=res.header='Access-Control-Allow-Origin','http://example.com'
WorkingDirectory=/opt/backend-service/operation
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node --experimental-worker /opt/backend-service/operation/node_modules/@gst/operation-service/www.js
TimeoutStopSec=10
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Presumably "CORS" is "cross-origin resource sharing", if I'm guessing correctly from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/add-cors-configuration.html? Also, is `private allowCrossDomain ...` a javascript function? How do you imagine integrating that into systemd? I see an attempt at adding an Environment variable, but is that really what you need?

Comment: sorry for not being so clear, I updated the question to make it more comprehensive. yes, that function is javascript and yes, I want to configure Cross Origin Resource Sharing in my systemd service. I added: Environment=res.header='Access-Control-Allow-Origin','http://example.com', but doesn't seem the service picks it up. any idea how I can set CORS in service level?

Comment: If you set these environment variables on your own, does it do what you want? I just don't see the connection between the environment variables and the javascript code you posted. The js code appears to set (or filter?) HTTP traffic, which is somewhat independent from environment variables.

Comment: i am not sure of what directive needs to be used for CORS in systemd, that is my exact question. using Environment directive is not correct since CORS is not environment variable.

Comment: Your example systemd service doesn't do anything; to integrate into systemd, it would help if you showed what the service should do (what it starts).

Comment: I updated the question with systemd service config.

Comment: @JeffSchaller, configuration was easy! I set the CORS option as environment variable in my code first then added that with Environment directive in systemd config, it worked just fine! I tried to post complete answer here for reference but couldn't: I answered it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57776064/how-to-configure-cors-in-systemd-service/57795160#57795160

Comment: I've reopened this question, since it appears SO wants to close that one. feel free to self-Answer here!

Answer (score 1):

this is how fixed the issue. add CORS options as environment variable in the code:

```
  private allowCrossDomain(req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: () => void) {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', process.env.CORS_ORIGIN_HOST || 'http://localhost:4200');
        ...
```

then add the Environment directive in systemd configuration:

```
[unit]
Description=Tool operation BE
After=network.target
[Service]
User=ubuntu
Environment=BACKEND_HOST=backend-ops-model.com
Environment=BACKEN_MODEL_PORT=80
Environment=CORS_ORIGIN_HOST=http://alterntive.com
WorkingDirectory=/opt/backend-service/operation
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node --experimental-worker /opt/backend-service/operation/node_modules/@gst/operation-service/www.js
TimeoutStopSec=10
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

with configuration above if you don't provide environment variable in systemd the localhost:4200 will be picked as default.
hope it helps others with the same issue.